# Retrieving selected cell information in dgrid (dojo)

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I am using dgrid component in my dojo project. I have one grid and a button.
I have enabled cell selection on the grid.

How to retrieve information(data) of the selected cell? My use case is whenever I click on button I should be able to get the data associated with selected cell in the grid.

I tried looking up documentation at https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/Components-Mixins but couldn't find any relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

In the example at https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/demos/dTuned/index.html, a grid is created by using mixins.

```
window.grid = new (declare([Grid, Selection, Keyboard, Hider]))({
    ...
}, "grid");
```

The selection mixin has the following property:

```
// selection:
//      An object where the property names correspond to 
//      object ids and values are true or false depending on whether an item is selected
selection: {},
```

Comment: My question is about dgrid(gridFromHtml) (Ref: https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid) and NOT about DataGrid in dojox. The above method does not work for dgrid.

Comment: My mistake.  I haven't used these widgets before.  But quickly looking at the code, I updated my answer.  Hope this helps.

Comment: how do you get the selection of a particular cell and not the whole row?

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example, implement a method to return the selected cells, using [*select*](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/Selection#property-summary) property and [*cell()*](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/Grid#method-summary) method from the grid.

```dojo
getSelectedCells: function() {
  var cell,
      results = [];

  for (var rowIdx in grid.selection) {
    for (var colIdx in grid.selection[rowIdx]) {
      cell = grid.cell(rowIdx, colIdx);
      results.push(cell);
    }
  }

  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CellSelection mixin](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v1.0.0/doc/components/mixins/CellSelection.md).

Selected cells can be accessed by `selection` object or inside `dgrid-select` and `dgrid-deselect` events by its `cells` property.

From mixin's documentation:

> The selection object stores a nested hash, where the outer hash is keyed by item ID and the inner hashes are keyed by column ID.
>
> The dgrid-select and dgrid-deselect events still fire, but include a cells property containing an array of cell objects, rather than a rows property.